# updating a sub document value with its old value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I want to round all prices persisted in this collection (that has a huge amount of documents) how can I do that without need to traverse on all documents and update each one?

input:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e05453d88ce103684d3b7e5"),//id is primary key for the root document
    "RoomTypes" : [
        {
            "Code" : "STDB",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
            "RatePlans" : [
                {
                    "Code":"standard",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                    "Rates" : [
                        {
                            "_value" : {
                                "Occupancy" : NumberInt(1),
                                "Currency" : "IRR",//(Occupancy an Currency are ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                                "Amount" : 3560.5,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "_value" : {
                                "Occupancy" : NumberInt(1),
                                "Currency" : "EURO",//(Occupancy an Currency are ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                                "Amount" : 35.5,
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e05453d88ce103684d3b7e5"),//id is primary key for the root document
    "RoomTypes" : [
        {
            "Code" : "STDB",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
            "RatePlans" : [
                {
                    "Code":"standard",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                    "Rates" : [
                        {
                            "_value" : {
                                "Occupancy" : NumberInt(1),
                                "Currency" : "IRR",//(Occupancy an Currency are ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                                "Amount" : 3560.2,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

expected result:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e05453d88ce103684d3b7e5"),//id is primary key for the root document
    "RoomTypes" : [
        {
            "Code" : "STDB",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
            "RatePlans" : [
                {
                    "Code":"standard",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                    "Rates" : [
                        {
                            "_value" : {
                                "Occupancy" : NumberInt(1),
                                "Currency" : "IRR",//(Occupancy an Currency are ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                                "Amount" : 3561,
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "_value" : {
                                "Occupancy" : NumberInt(1),
                                "Currency" : "EURO",//(Occupancy an Currency are ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                                "Amount" : 36,
                            }
                        }

                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e05453d88ce103684d3b7e5"),//id is primary key for the root document
    "RoomTypes" : [
        {
            "Code" : "STDB",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
            "RatePlans" : [
                {
                    "Code":"standard",//(Code is ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                    "Rates" : [
                        {
                            "_value" : {
                                "Occupancy" : NumberInt(1),
                                "Currency" : "IRR",//(Occupancy an Currency are ducument leve primary key for this subdocument)
                                "Amount" : 3560,
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: mongo version is v4.2.1

Comment: If you want to update all documents in the collection you have to update each document. There is no way you can transform a field's value for all the documents in the collection without traversing the documents. Every document you want to update need to be accessed and updated. You may not have to write a _for-each_ loop for this, since you are using MongoDB version 4.2.1, the [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) method with _aggregation_ (instead of an _update_) can be used.

Comment: @parsad can you describe more about the update method with aggregation? can I use $unwind keyword in update command to unwind the documents then update them?

Comment: _can you describe more about the update method with aggregation?_ Please see the link for `updateMany` in my previous comment - it has all information about the update method including examples.

Comment: _can I use $unwind keyword in update command to unwind the documents then update them?_ I don't think so. The documentation says only the following aggregation stages can be used:`$addFields and its alias $set`, `$project and its alias $unset` and `$replaceRoot and its alias $replaceWith`.